# Why does the KeyDown event bubble up from a TextBox?

Tags: wpf, keyboard

If I type a letter into a TextBox, and its content changes according to my keypress, why does the KeyDown event continue bubbling up?  I would have thought this would be 'handled' at this stage.

Comment: How did you verify that it bubbles up?

Comment: The KeyDown event of my Window fires

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `KeyDown` event is a `bubbling event`, that's why its bubbled to its parent in your case  Window. If you don't want that to bubbled to your window, you need to mark it as handled in your textBox handler itself like this -

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Whereas, if you try to hook the event `PreviewKeyDown` in your textBox, you will see that - Window's PreviewKeyDownEvent gets called first and later that of your textBox. Reason behind that is, it's a `tunelling event`. For routing strategies, refer to this link - [Routing Strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)

**EDIT**
Morevoer, if you want to check if the KeyDown event comes from textBox, you can check the `OriginalSource` of your eventArgs -

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Check to make sure event comes from window and not from textbox.
    if(e.OriginalSource is Window)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: But surely it shouldn't be bubbled if it's been handled?

Comment: Yes, it won't bubbled if it's handled below.

Comment: Why doesn't the TextBox handle the event automatically?

Comment: This is desired behaviour since in some cases we want the same event to be handled on parent control for some processing. That's why microsoft gave power in your hands to stop the bubbling if you don't want to handle it in parent window.